# Why does my RichTextBox not activate its events vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, richtextbox

Okay so i found this code on stackoverflow and i implemented it into a new class file in my project.

```
    Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

    Public Class MyRichTextBox
        Inherits RichTextBox
        <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
        Public Shared Function GetScrollPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nBar As Integer) As Integer
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
        Private Shared Function SetScrollPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nBar As Integer, ByVal nPos As Integer, ByVal bRedraw As Boolean) As Integer
        End Function

        Private Const SB_HORZ As Integer = &H0
        Private Const SB_VERT As Integer = &H1

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets and Sets the Horizontal Scroll position of the control.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property HScrollPos() As Integer
            Get
                Return GetScrollPos(DirectCast(Me.Handle, IntPtr), SB_HORZ)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                SetScrollPos(DirectCast(Me.Handle, IntPtr), SB_HORZ, value, True)
            End Set
        End Property

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets and Sets the Vertical Scroll position of the control.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property VScrollPos() As Integer
            Get
                Return GetScrollPos(DirectCast(Me.Handle, IntPtr), SB_VERT)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                SetScrollPos(DirectCast(Me.Handle, IntPtr), SB_VERT, value, True)
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

After I implemented the code into my project I realized to replace my RichTextBox i would have to change most of my code. Seeking a faster way to do this, i placed the following code in my form1_Load event.

```
 RichTextBox1 = New MyRichTextBox
```

So now RichTextBox1 is a MyRichTextBox

and because MyRichTextBox implements RichTextBox it should have the same events.

But my RichTextbox.TextChanged event does not work. Now if I remove that line above from the form1_load it works fine. Whats wrong?

**EDIT**

So i found out that MyRichTextBox does NOT have the same events as a RichTextBox... How would I add those events?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

Add the textchanged event in side the class

example

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
    Imports System.Windows.Forms
    Namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

        Public Class MyRichTextBox
            Inherits RichTextBox
            <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
            Public Shared Function GetScrollPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nBar As Integer) As Integer
            End Function

            <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
            Private Shared Function SetScrollPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nBar As Integer, ByVal nPos As Integer, ByVal bRedraw As Boolean) As Integer
            End Function

            Private Const SB_HORZ As Integer = &H0
            Private Const SB_VERT As Integer = &H1

......
.........
..........
........
......


''' Add the Event



            Protected Overrides Sub OnTextChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

                MsgBox(Me.Text)
                MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
            End Sub

        End Class

    End Namespace
```

In Load Event

```
 Dim RichTextBox1 As New WindowsFormsApplication1.MyRichTextBox
    Me.Controls.Add(RichTextBox1)
```